# How can I set focus on an input field in dynatree title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I use Dynatree to get a tree view and now I want to set the focus on an input field in the dynatree title element but the element loses the focus.

Unfortunately my code doesn't work. You can see it in a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/3nD7X/1/). When you click on the last level on the numbers in front of the text, then the input field appears, but the focus is set on the dynatree element. When I click on the input box the focus appears and then disappears again when my finger releases the mouse (mouse up).

```
$('#tree-team').on('click', '.seeding_list', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#label_place_' + id).hide();
    $('#input_place_' + id).show();
}).change(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    console.log("change seeding place");
});

$('#tree-team').on('mouseup', '.tree-editbox', function() {
    return false;
});

$(document).mouseup(function() {
    $('.tree-editbox').hide();
    $('.tree-text').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not that familiar with Dynantree and perhaps this is crude, but what worked for me is replacing

```
$('#input_place_' + id).show().;
```

with

```
$('#input_place_' + id).blur(function(){$(this).focus()}).show().focus();
```

Handling `.blur()` event prevents control from losing focus and using last `.focus()` actually sets the focus

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/3nD7X/4/

Comment: Glad it worked for you. You may want to fine-tune it a bit more, e.g. take `.blur()` assignment outside of `$('#tree-team').on('click'..` event so it won't be bound on every click.